# Azure Ad domain connecting Azure VM

Tags: azure

I am facing the the problem to connect Azure Ad domain in Azure VM. While enter the credentials to connect the domain from server manager Work Group. Please let me know Which credentials exactly use in this case.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdyED.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the account of one of the Azure AD administrators' password.